# Duplicate entries are returning when filtering model

Tags: django, django-models

```
//Model
class ClientUserSelectedPodcast(AuditModel):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_selected_podcast',
                                       null=True,blank=True)
    client_unit = models.ForeignKey(Unit, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_selected_unit', null=True, blank=True)
    client_superunit = models.ForeignKey(SuperUnit, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_selected_super_unit', null=True, blank=True)
    selected_type = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="FAVOURITE")

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-pk',)  


//view


class GetNewClientsCountViewSet(APIView):
    def get(self,request,*args, **kwargs):
        from podcast.api_serializers import UnitMiniSerializer
        from datetime import datetime
        data=[]
        total_listener_count={}
        client_count=Client.get_new_clients_count()
        gender_wise_count={}
        # gets the podcast unit count of this month
        podcast_count=Unit.get_new_podcast_unit_count()
        user_counts=ClientUser.get_new_client_user_count()
        most_listened_units,most_liked_units=ClientUserSelectedPodcast.get_total_listened_liked_podcast()
        inhouse_listened_units,inhouse_liked_units=ClientUserSelectedInhouse.get_total_listened_liked_inhouse()
        podcast_listener_count=ClientUserSelectedPodcast.get_total_podcast_listeners()
        inhouse_listener_count=ClientUserSelectedInhouse.get_total_inhouse_listeners()
        podcast_wise_count=ClientUserSelectedPodcast.get_gender_wise_listeners()
        inhouse_wise_count=ClientUserSelectedInhouse.get_gender_wise_inhouse_listeners()

        total_listener_count['podcast']=podcast_listener_count
        total_listener_count['inhouse']=inhouse_listener_count
        
        gender_wise_count['podcast']=podcast_wise_count
        gender_wise_count['inhouse']=inhouse_wise_count
        
        # most liked show of this month
        most_liked_show= (
            ClientUserSelectedPodcast.objects
            .filter(selected_type='FAVOURITE', created_at__month=datetime.now().month)
        )
        print(most_liked_show)
        
        data.append({
            'clients':client_count,
            'podcast':podcast_count,
            'user':user_counts,
            'total_listener_count':total_listener_count,
            'most_listened_units':most_listened_units,
            'most_liked_units':most_liked_units,
            'inhouse_listened_units':inhouse_listened_units,
            'inhouse_liked_units':inhouse_liked_units,
            'gender_wise_count':gender_wise_count
        })
        
        return Response(data)
```

i want to get the Most liked show for this month i.e selected*type='FAVOURITE'.

```
Queryset:  
<QuerySet [
<ClientUserSelectedPodcast: ClientUserSelectedPodcast object (552)\>, 
<ClientUserSelectedPodcast: ClientUserSelectedPodcast object (551)\>, 
<ClientUserSelectedPodcast: ClientUserSelectedPodcast object (550)\>]
```

The problem here is that query is returing different objects but the value in them is same ie the object 552 and 551 has the same entries i.e

```
552 -\> {'user':224, clientunit:'94ba2e2a47254028b0d3d59eeb5b257d', 'selected\*\_type':FAVOURITE'},  
551-\> *{'user':224, clientunit:'94ba2e2a47254028b0d3d59eeb5b257d', 'selected*\_type':FAVOURITE'}
```

What i want if this occurs duplicate occurs i want to take the count as one and want to return the most liked show for this month